# APNS resend notification when wifi not connected

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

when sending push notification, receiver side has not connected to wifi, Does APNS resend  the notification when they connected back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ["Local and Push Notification Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW7):

> APNs retains the last notification it receives from a provider for an
>   application on a device; so, if a device or computer comes online and
>   has not received the notification, APNs pushes the stored notification
>   to it. A device running iOS receives push notifications over both
>   Wi-Fi and cellular connections; a computer running OS X receives push
>   notifications over both WiFi and Ethernet connections.

So the answer to your question is YES (for the *last* notification).